# Unique numbers in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, math

I'm trying to efficiently list numbers between 1 and 100. However I have to get rid of numbers with same digits.
**Example:**
12 according to this rule is the same of 21
13 is 31
14 is 41
so the for loop it won't go over the same numbers.
I'm thinking a few tricks such as getting all the numbers from 1 to 100 and then deleting the found permutations of current number.
The reason I'm asking this because in large limits like 100000 it will fail.
**Another example:**  124 is equal to 142,241,214,412,421

Comment: Why do you have to get rid of numbers with the same digits?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Looks like a homework. What problems do you have writing the code ?

Comment: No, it's not a homework. I'm seeking for efficient solutions since I can apply a naive approach by myself.

Comment: Where's the code for your naive solution?

Comment: I'll write if no efficient solution found, again im not asking for code. A methodology would be enough

Comment: yes but it is also the same for 101,110 like that

Comment: I was thinking that you'd need only numbers where the (n)th digit is greater or equal to the (n-1)th - since if you encounter, for instance, 31, you'll know that you already have the smaller number 13, so you won't need the 31. Does that help?

Comment: Yes but what I'm trying to get is this: A loop that has 50 million as the upper limit works real slow. I'm trying to increase the execution time of the loop by decreasing the numbers to work on. if 13 and the numbers 130,103 can be omitted from the numbers to be checked maybe the loop time would decrease. That's what im trying to achieve

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply recursion. Prototype of this function is then like:

```
print_digits(int num_of_remaining_digits,int start_from_digit, int current_number);
```

EDIT: for completion  I present here my solution (i think it has better readbility than from Ben Voigt and ascending output order

```
void print_digits(int num_of_remaining_digits,int start_from_digit, int current_number)
{
  if(num_of_remaining_digits == 0) 
  {
    std::cout << current_number << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  for(int i=start_from_digit;i<=9;i++)
  {
     print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,i,10*current_number+i);
  }
}
```

and here is testing code

http://ideone.com/Xm8Mv

How this works?

It is one of classics in recursion. First there is stopping condition. And then there is main loop.
Main loop where goes from `start_from_digit` because all generated digits will be in non decreasing order.  For instance if `current_number` is `15`  it will call `print_digits` whith

```
print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,5,155)
print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,6,156)
print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,7,157)
print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,8,158)
print_digits(num_of_remaining_digits-1,9,159)
```

In each call it will check if we reached end whit `num_of_remaining_digits` and if not will continue from digit that is pushed as `start_from_digit` (2nd param) using `current_number`

Comment: Incredible! Thanks. Exactly what I've needed

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit in detail?

Comment: When the question is tagged `performance`, best to stay away from `std::cout`.  Otherwise an excellent solution.

Comment: If you replace cout whith printf it will run 3 times faster and extra 3 times faster if you replace this code whith code from Ben Voigt.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I got the question wrong, but should 11 and 22 etc really be a part of the list? Aren't they the same as 1 and 2 respectively?

Comment: Also shouldn't 10 *be* a part of the list?

Comment: Same numbers are numbers that has same number of digits, but in different order. I am not sure about 10, but this program does not produce 10. 10 is same kind of number as 01

Answer (score 3):

You're look for combination of some characters (0..9) with a certain length (100=2, 1000=3).

Take a look here [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: Thank you Fabio, looks like something that can help me out

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a class suiting your comparision needs by overloading the correct operators (from the top of my head that should be only `less`) and go with a `std::set`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a hash table, something like this

1) Derive a key from the number derived in such a way that digits with the same number have the same key (e.g. sum the digits, so "124" and "142" have the key 7, or take the product of the digits(+1), so "124" and "142" have the key 30 - have to +1 for the digit 0)

2) Put the numbers in a hash table indexed by its key

Now the test as to whether you already have a number with the same digits is limited to entities in the hash table with the same key. This algorithm requires linear storage and its performance depends on how good a key you can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

First, observe that your rule excludes multiples of 11.  (Why?)

Start by generating all 2-digit numbers with the first digit = 1.

Now, generate all 2-digit numbers with the first digit = 2, but don't generate any numbers that match numbers in the first list.

Repeat for 3, but don't generate any numbers from the first two lists.

Observe that, for any 2-digit number ab, for it to qualify, it must be the case that a < b, or you would have already generated the corresponding number ba.

In PASCAL, just because I'm feeling ornery:

```
var i:integer;  j:integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 8 do
    for j := i+1 to 9 do
      println(i*10+j);
end;
```

ADDED A LITTLE LATER

Observe that the numbers you want to generate will always have their digits strictly monotonically increasing.  For a number 2abc to qualify, observe that 2 < a < b < c.  (Example: 2539 is a match for 2359 and should be rejected.)

Comment: a<b rang a few bells in my mind. I'll check that out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t enum_canonical(char* begin, char* end, char min, char max)
{
    if (begin == end) {
        puts(begin);
        putchar('\n');
        return 1;
    }

    size_t result_count = 0;
    --end;
    for( *end = min; *end <= max; ++*end )
        result_count += enum_canonical(begin, end, min, *end);

    return result_count;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buff[7];
    printf("%d results\n", enum_canonical(buff, &(buff[6] = '\0'), '0', '9'));
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/BWGdg

Comment: @rolandbishop: Please note that this is effectively the same [approach mentioned by ralu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056758/103167).

Comment: +1 , but still this code will run as fast as yours http://ideone.com/RTXqQ :)

Comment: @ralu: Sure, but I didn't hardcode the `'9'` :-p

Comment: I noticed that, Agree. You can also produce permutations of chars. I kind a like your approach even better. At least I have learned somthing abott cout. Do you know why it is that slow?

Comment: @ralu: `cout` is slow partly because there are so very many options (`imbue` can completely change the behavior, at runtime) and partly because it seems like library vendors don't put much effort into optimizing it.  You might be interested in a couple of the questions I asked, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A103167+is%3Aquestion+%5Bperformance%5D

Answer (score 1):

Lets take 1 to 1000. Since there are 4 digits in 1000, I print 1 as 0001, so 0001, 0010, 0100, 1000 are same number as per my algorithm. Also 0120, 0012, 0210, 0102, 0201, 0021 are same numbers.

Here is the program:

```
int main()
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;

    while(i<=9)
    {
        int unique=(i*100 + j*10 + k);
        printf("unique number : %3d\n", unique);

        if(j==9 && k==9)
        {
            i++;
            k=i;
            j=i;
        }
        else if(k==9)
        {
            j++;
            k=j;
        }
        else 
            k++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it can be as simple as this:

```
list = {}
for (j = 1 to 100)
     if (j is not excluded from list)
          list += j;
```

Really, only the `if` condition is interesting:  needs to examine all relevant properties of the list items.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which takes a string, and returns an array of strings with all the possible permutations of the characters in that string. It wouldn't be hard, but it would probably be easiest to make recursive. Though, easier said than done.

Once you have that function, and it returns the array, you simply go through the array and remove the indecies which share a common number with one in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The trouble I have is that when I try to apply this approach when the upper limit is like >=50 million the algorithm works real slow. I've tried doing nothing in the loop but incrementing a paremeter but even that takes more than 10 secs.

Comment: Then you have a problem, because this is the only reasonable way to test every possible permutation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `set` for the permutations of the digits of the number:

```
std::vector<int> list_unwanted = digit_permutations(number);
std::unordered_set<int> set_unwanted(begin(list_unwanted), end(list_unwanted));
```

Then loop from 0 to the limit, not adding unwanted numbers by checking if they're in the set `set_unwanted`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
numbers.reserve(limit - set_unwanted.count());

for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    if (!set_unwanted.count(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of digits, a whatever permutation of this set is not a valid solution, so first of all make a function to estabilish if a set of digits is a permutation of another set.
To get single digits you can divide by 10 recursively, until you get a zero value.
If you put all the digits in an array like [1,2,4], to check if antoher array is a permutation (you check it only if they have the same length) of antoher set:

```
bool permutation(int *a, int *b, int n) // n leading dimension
{
    bool result=true, vector[n]={false};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n ;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
                vector[i]=false;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n && result;i++)
        result=(vector[i]==true);   // if vector[i] is false, result is false, is
                                    // not a permutation and the loop ends
    return result;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it works, otherwise tell me.
As for putting all digits in an array, I think it's pretty easy.
Once generating all numbers, you check that a certain number is not a permutation of an already taken number.

Comment: If i didn't understand wrong it applies as if a number is a permutation of the prefound number. Thank you for contribution but I'm more like trying not to **not** look for the future numbers. In case number 124 found the loop **shouldn't** go over the 241,214 once again.

Comment: I realized now that it's wrong, if I have an array [1,1,1] and [1,2,3], this function returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea, for each value put the digits of it in a set. Use that set as a key to another set that keeps track of which numbers have been used. In my case I use a bit field as a set for the digits, i.e. digit 0 is represented by a 1, digit 1 is represented by a 2 (2 by a 4 and so on). Too tired to explain, here's tha codez:

```
unsigned int get_digits(int v)
{
  unsigned int rv = 0;
  do
  {
    rv |= 1 << (v % 10);
    v /= 10;
  } while(v);
  return rv;
}

void unique_ints(int n)
{
  std::set<unsigned int> used_combinations;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    const unsigned int d = get_digits(i);
    if(used_combinations.find(d) == used_combinations.end())
    {
      used_combinations.insert(d);
      // cout or some other way to store the value
      std::cout << i <<  std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```